# Проверка по внешнему ключу не работает SQLite3 при вводе через discord

Tags: python, sql, discord, discord.py, sqlite3

Есть три таблицы со связью Многие ко Многим, две primary key и одна связующая их с каскадным обновлением и удалением.

Для удобства понимания:

```
CREATE TABLE tag_art (
    artID INT NOT NULL
              REFERENCES art (idA) ON UPDATE CASCADE
                                   ON DELETE CASCADE,
    tagID TEXT NOT NULL
              REFERENCES tag (idT) ON UPDATE CASCADE
                                   ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tagart PRIMARY KEY (
        artID,
        tagID
    )
);
```

Если я в sqlite studio или консоль ввожу `INSERT INTO tag_art (artID, tagID) VALUES (1, 'test')`, то это не сработает, потому что в таблице tag нет значения test в столбце idT. Всё выполняется правильно. Если вместо test введу существующее значения, то оно позволит такой ввод данных.

**Суть:** это перестаёт работать, если тот же самый запрос поступает не напрямую, а через discord чат и команду.
Пример:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import sqlite3

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents) 

with sqlite3.connect("name.db") as adb:
    cur = adb.cursor()

    @bot.command()
    async def test(ctx):
        cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO tag_art (artID, tagID) VALUES
        ('1', 'test')
        """)
        adb.commit()
        await ctx.send("Данные успешно приняты!")

bot.run('token')
```

Такой ввод оно пропускает и вводит значение test, обходя ограничение через внешний ключ, хотя запрос идентичный.

Но если ввести уже существующее значение, то оно его заблокирует и не даст выполнить команду, а значит проверка всё же работает, но только частично.
Если вручную затем в программе попробовать изменить это значение на другое неподходящее, то не позволит, как и должно быть.

Если у вас есть идеи почему так происходит, как discord обходит ограничение foreign key и как это можно решить, буду рад любому ответу по делу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне удалось найти решение проблемы. Дело в том, что в SQLite3 необходимо включать проверку ограничения по внешним ключам каждый раз, иначе оно будет пропускать любые значения.

**Решается буквально одной строчкой, после подключения к базе:**

```
with sqlite3.connect("name.db") as adb:
    cur = adb.cursor()
    cur.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;")
```

Теперь всё работает верно и выдаёт ошибку, если ввести несуществующие значения.
Уверен, многим поможет данная информация.

Comment: Да, всё верно. [Enabling Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) - документация.